# Trying to set X-Powered-By header, no luck

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to set a custom X-Powered-By header in PHP. I set it at the end of my document, and it doesnt't show up when I use cURL to see the headers.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php
header('X-Powered-By: Riverside Rocks');
die();
?>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in your logs?

Comment: Do you already output any content? If so this won't work. Move it to the top of your file so it is output before any content.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - Some file was messing everything up, it was listed in my error log and may have messed with the headers.

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/includes/tracking.html:1) in /var/www/html/includes/header.php on line 5, referer:
```